# Linq caching issue?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ado.net

I am very new to Linq and I am having what I think is a caching issue. All the "clearing the cache" tricks I have googled haven't worked. Basically if I click start in Visual Studio the record gets added and is echoed out in the Linq results. However if I run the executable it adds the new record but the Linq output never gets updated. Even after the program exits and is re-run the previous added record doesn't show until you recompile the code. Here is my code.

```
    static void Main()
    {


        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting insert");
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Test\\Database1.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Contacts (forname, initial, surname, dob) VALUES (@forname, @initial, @surname, @dob)", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forname", "Sarah");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@initial", "J");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", "Jones");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", "04/24/1972 12:00:00");
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {
            db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, db.Contacts);


            var contacts = from c in db.Contacts select c;

            foreach (Contact co in contacts)
            {
                Console.Write("ID: " + co.Id.ToString() + "\n");
                Console.Write("First name: " + co.forname + "\n");
                Console.Write("Surname: " + co.surname + "\n");
                Console.Write("Date of Birth" + co.dob.ToString() + "\n\n");
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Is the ef-context connected to the same database? I'm expecting the first part of your code is connected to the database in your visual-studio-solution, and the second part of your code to be connected to the database in the bin/debug folder.

Comment: Yes, I took the connection string from the server explorer.

Comment: Can you show the connection-strings from the app.config?

Comment: Sorted it. Put the full path of the db file in the App.config connection string

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection strings and database locations. I'm expecting the first part of your code to connect to the database you have in your visual-studio-solution, and the second part of your code to connect to the database in the bin/debug folder. This would explain why the added record is only visible **after** re-compilation, since at that moment the database from the visual-studio-solution is copied to the bin/debug folder.